# Meteor call in a loop. How to prevent multiple call?

Tags: reactjs, meteor

The method call "Insert All sms data" run more than once I tried to prevent using counter variable but on client side it run once and on the server side it runs x time as shown in the image, thus adding data to db multiple timres which I do not want, this should add to db only once. I want also add another call whith in method call "Insert All sms data" which should run x as the loop. I stuck here.
Meteor 1.8 react 16.8

imports/api/kuser.js

```
'Find all numbers' (smsText) {
        if(!this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
         }
         let counter = 0;
          return userKisandb.find({
            userId: this.userId
         }).fetch().map((Mob) => {
            // return Mob.Mnumber
            if(Mob.Mnumber) {

                Meteor.call('Send to all',Mob.Mnumber,smsText,(err,resp) => {
                  //sms.js
                  if(err){
                      console.log("send all numbers error2", err);
                    } else {
                      console.log("send all numbers ", resp);

                      if(counter === 0) {
                        Meteor.call('Insert All sms data',smsText,counter,(err,resp1) => {
                          //get inserted data id
                          //allSmsdb
                          if(err){
                              console.log("Insert All sms data error", err);
                            } else {
                              console.log("this should run only once ",counter);

                  //Another call to be added which should run x times
                            }
                          })
                          counter++
                        }

                    }

                  });

            } //Mob.Mnumber

         });
    },
```

and the method 1 is

```
'Send to all'(mob,text) {
      return "sucess";
  },
```

method 2 is

```
'Insert All sms data' (smstext,counter) {
        if(!this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorized');
         }
         console.log("Inserted same data x times",counter);
         if(counter === 0) {
            return allSms.insert({
                smstext,
                userId: this.userId,
                updatedAt: moment().valueOf(),
            });
         }

    },
```

And output is 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Meteor methods can be called from the front end, asking the back end to do something. It doesn't make sense for a back end method to do a `Meteor.call`, because it's already on the back end. It will work, kind of, but then you get into trouble because your counter isn't passed around as you expect.

Make your method only work on the server, and just loop around the data, doing all of the work, rather than breaking it up into pieces like you have.

Comment: There are multiple db collection that is why I used call here, I dont want to import here,  I will try another way or by import. Thnx for pointing this situation.

Comment: Doing an import is much cheaper than doing a `Meteor.call()`. If you don't want to import the collection into this script, you can put the code in a simple utility function, import that, and call it (without the overhead of `Meteor.call()`